# Spring <form:select> tag and command object did not match

Tags: java, forms, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using spring in my project. As spring automatically fills form fields that came from command object. There comes a comboBox case where command object was having value **newtypename** (lowerCase) and the list, that was populating comboBox have this name as **NewTypeName** (camelCase). These values did not match and my comboBox value was not automatically selected.

When I set command object having value **NewTypeName**; it matched and the form loaded with this value selected in comboBox.

```
<form:select multiple="single" path="pluginType" id="pluginType" cssClass="dropDownSelect-small" tabindex="3" onchange="changeState()">
    <form:option value="0" label="Select" />
    <form:options items="${pluginTypeList}" />
</form:select>
```

How can I achieve a situation where all cases run perfect i.e. whether I type lowerCase or camel Case. I should get that value selected in comboBox.

Comment: Java is indeed case sensitive

Comment: Yes it is; but what to do with this issue :(

Comment: @NimChimpsky: Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JAVA is case sensitive so comboBox case issue where command object was having value newtypename (lowerCase) and the list, that was populating comboBox have this name as NewTypeName (camelCase) is fixed with business logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're trying to do here...

Option 1: If you can change the values in the options list, that would be one approach:

```
<form:options items="${fn.toLowerCase(pluginTypeList)}" />
```

This requires loading the JSTL function library.

Most likely you can't just change those values because the application is already in use.

Option 2: make the value for the options control the lowercase version of the displayed value. 
This would require changes to the processing logic for the form.

Option 3: you'd need to implement a 'to camel case' method, which seems like a kludge.